# make: *** [all] Error 2 when building Trilinos

Tags: makefile, linker-errors, trilinos

I am trying to build Trilinos from source on Kubuntu 14.04 as a prerequisite to installing Peridigm. I am following the build instructions [here](http://trilinos.org/oldsite/TrilinosBuildQuickRef.html) and am using [this](https://peridigm.sandia.gov/content/trilinos) configuration script suggested for Peridigm.

Configuration works fine, but when I try to actually build Trilinos using `make` I end up with the following error:

```
Linking CXX static library libpamgen.a
[ 24%] Built target pamgen
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am rather new to Linux and have virtually no experience in manually building libraries. Any help in making sense of this would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is the output from `make VERBOSE=1` right before the error as requested by @EtanReisner:

```
/usr/local/lib/trilinos/trilinos-11.4.3-Source/packages/epetra/src/Epetra_Import_Util.cpp: In instantiation of ‘int Epetra_Import_Util::TLowCommunicationMakeColMapAndReindex(int, const int*, int*, const int_type*, const Epetra_Map&, const int*, bool, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, MapType1&) [with int_type = long long int; MapType1 = Epetra_BlockMap; MapType2 = Epetra_Map]’:
/usr/local/lib/trilinos/trilinos-11.4.3-Source/packages/epetra/src/Epetra_Import_Util.cpp:700:198:   required from here
/usr/local/lib/trilinos/trilinos-11.4.3-Source/packages/epetra/src/Epetra_Import_Util.cpp:639:10: warning: variable ‘ElementSizeList’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
/usr/local/lib/trilinos/trilinos-11.4.3-Source/packages/epetra/src/Epetra_MultiVector.cpp: In member function ‘int Epetra_MultiVector::Abs(const Epetra_MultiVector&)’:
/usr/local/lib/trilinos/trilinos-11.4.3-Source/packages/epetra/src/Epetra_MultiVector.cpp:1172:63: internal compiler error: in prepare_cmp_insn, at optabs.c:4190
     for (int j=0; j < myLength; j++) to[j] = std::abs(from[j]);
                                                               ^
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs> for instructions.
Preprocessed source stored into /tmp/ccxuxXUm.out file, please attach this to your bugreport.
make[2]: *** [packages/epetra/src/CMakeFiles/epetra.dir/Epetra_MultiVector.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [packages/epetra/src/CMakeFiles/epetra.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Run `make VERBOSE=1` and paste what you get when it fails.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Here are the last few lines of output before it fails (which this time occurs at a different library):

make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/trilinos'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /usr/local/trilinos/CMakeFiles  56 57 58
[ 32%] Built target chaco
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/trilinos'
make: *** [all] Error 2

I would like to post more, but the previous command fills two pages and SteckOverflow prohibits me from posting it.

Comment: Put it in the post not a comment and we also need the output right before make starts reporting the error.

Comment: The first message fails after trying to build `pamgen`; the second example fails after building `chaco`.  Are you sure you're not running make with parallel builds enabled (`make -jX`), and/or using the `-k` option to make?  It looks to me like something else is failing, well before the messages you're showing us, and because of parallel builds or "keep going" flags make is not stopping at the failure but continuing on.  You should redirect the output of make to a log file, then look for the FIRST error messages in the output, not the last thing printed.

Comment: @MadScientist: Thank you for the hint about the -j flag. I reran make without it and posted what I think is the critical part above. Can anything be done about an internal compiler error?

Comment: I'm not sure about the compiler issue; it's possible there really is a bug in your code, and the compiler is just not handling it properly.  I suggest you send an email to the gcc@gcc.gnu.org mailing list with a code example and the above set of errors (please include, there, the GCC command line that was invoked, which you forgot to do above).  In the future, please specify EXACTLY what command you are invoking; you said you were running `make` but you really ran `make -j`; that's _critical_ information.  Best is to cut/paste the command line and the complete error, including compile line.

Comment: It seems to have been a compiler issue. I updated GCC to version 4.9.2 (from 4.8.2) and compilation worked fine this time.

PS: I'm not sure what code example I should include. As I said, I am not compiling any code of my own by the Trilinos library itself.